# if a linux program exit with coredump, the unclosed files may lead a resource leak

Tags: linux, coredump, resource-leak

As we know, the os will clean up any allocated memory after the program exited. but how about the opened or created files after coredump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will close them as well.  Although core dump abruptly terminates the program, the OS can still perform all normal clean-up routines it would do if the program terminated correctly.